# how to add validation to JPA Entities where it requires to query the entity to perform validation

Tags: java, validation, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Suppose I've following entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Integer counter;
    private Integer someVal;
}
```

I want to have CRUD operations and some additional methods on this Entity,
hence I have a repository such as

```
@Repository
public interface MyModelRepository extends JpaRepository<MyModel, Long> {}
```

Question:
I want to add certain validations on save, where I need to query the models.

Eg: on save, check the value of someVal is greater than the someVal of MyModel whose counter is one less than currently saving object.

PS: It could be cross Entity validations as well.
PS: I still need to use automatic crud generated by JpaRepository.

Otherwise, I've to implement DAO and write custom implementations and then map it to RestController.

What I would ideally want is customization of some parts while keeping rest of the magic.

Comment: Interestingly, none of the spring-boot books on safari online, deals with validation of model objects. Not  even simple validations using Validators. Nor virtual fields. If you are a technical author, jump in.

Comment: Currently, lives with a rest controller, which overrides the path used by JpaRepository. But that does not enforce validations for the users of JpaRepository.

Comment: What about the Spring Data Rest manual http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#validation  You can use the standard Spring MVC validation  mechanisms i.e. JSR303/310 annotations or by creating a Custom Validator:http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Comment: @AlanHay  Isn't this same as my work around. I have to add a custom Validator into a custom controller then  add mappings for the required REST methods.  PS: I am sure, following standard will have it's advantages.

Comment: What *exactly* is your question?

Comment: Is it about the question in comments referring you? In that case, my initial work around was to create a rest controller and map post and put to a method, in which do the validation. While as your suggestion is to use Validator  and move the validation there, instead of writing validation logic directly  in the controller. So,  the question was what advantages does the suggested approach have against my work around.

Comment: The SDR manual clearly explains you can add validation to a repository exposed as a REST resource. You do not need a custom controller.

Comment: Oh,  can you point me there.  That will be great.

Comment: Please also note that,  I'll be needing other repositories inside the Validator.

Comment: ???I pointed you there in my first comment

Comment: I tried that, not managed to get it working. If you could write an answer with sample wiring, I will accept the answer.

ie., how to inject Validator into JpaRepository and use it for save?

Comment: If it is not working then post some code because the process is clearly outlined here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#validation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133162/discussion-between-kra3-and-alan-hay).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone wonder, how I solved it:

## Method 1: Original way

```
@RestController
public class MyModelController {
   // autowired MyModelRepository & other models repositories
    
   @RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT})
   public long save(MyModel model){
       // added validation here (which involves queries to both repositories
       // returned saved entity.id or failed with 0
   }
}
```

## Method 2:

Obviously, question was about a better approach.
As @Alan Hay suggested using `Validator`, but still with Controller. Document was not clear on how to bind the `Validator` to `Repository` without a controller override.

```
public class MyModelValidator implements Validator{
   // Autowired MyModel repository and others
   // override both supports() and validate()
   // PS: moved validation logic from Controller in method 1 to validate()
}
```

Now changed the controller as:

```
@RestController
public class MyModelController {
   // autowired MyModelRepository & other models repositories
   // autowire MyModelValidator as mymodelValidator
    
   @RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT})
   public long save(@ModelAttribute("myModel") MyModel model, BindingResult result){
       mymodelValidator.validate(model, result);

       if(result.hasErrors()){
        // return 0
       }
       // save & return saved entity's id
   }
}
```

## Method 3: How it is done, finally.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener(ValidatingRepositoryEventListener validatingListener) {
        validatingListener.addValidator("beforeCreate", new MyModelValidator());
        validatingListener.addValidator("beforeSave", new MyModelValidator());
    }
}
```

Comment: w.r.t. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#validation : configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener is deprecated.

Comment: Actually `configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener` is deprecated in `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` but being added into `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter`.  By extending that into you ApplicationContext and implementing `configureValidatingRepositoryEventListener` one could do away with custom controllers as said in the answer.